# Removing/Hiding duplicate rows in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I have rows which are repeating , I need only unique values. How can I do that

```
Name|Account|Note
John|123456 |note1
John|123456 |note1
```

should be

```
Name|Account|Note
John|123456 |note1
```

Answer (score 0):

Unique combinations of fields can be grouped either in the SQL or in the report. In SQL you would use a `GROUP BY` clause. In the SSRS report, you would use a row group. In this case, you could set it to group on `Account`. This tells the report to show one row per account. Then, if there are different `Note` values from different dates for example, you have to decide which one(s) you want it to show for each account.